# Converter response data de HTML para PDF

Tags: javascript, axios, vue.js

O meu `response.data` está retornado um boleto no formato HTML, quero convertê-lo para PDF. Como faço?

Abaixo uma parte do código:

```
imprimirboleto: function () {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/server/boleto',
        params: {
            banco : this.banco,
            valor : this.valor,
        }
    }).then(function (response)
    {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=800,height=600, resizable, scrollbars,status")
        myWindow.document.write(response.data) // aqui quero abrir em pdf

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: Talvez https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pdf possa ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo a biblioteca [PDFKit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit), ela faz a "conversão" de HTML para PDF, já utilizei e é muito boa